# How to make the red squiggly line go away while putting providedIn: 'root' angular 7?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript, dependency-injection

As in the documentation. I have put providedIn : 'root in the @Injectable() attribute. However, I just get some red showing an error as follows. I spent a long time trying to figure out what the problem was only to find that the code seems to run.

[image]

I can't find any information online on this problem. Can anyone explain what the issue is here? And a better question is how is anyone supposed to make any sense of that signature?

```
((({ prfovidedln: Object | "root")) & Object) | 
(({ providedln: Object | 'root") & Object) | 
(({providedin: Object | "root")) & Object) | 
(({providedln: Object | "root")) & Object) | 
(({providedln: Object | "root"}) & Object) |
(((providedln: Object | "root"}) & Object))
```

Comment: Isn’t that your IDE problem? Probably it is simply outdated version of jetbrains, I saw it a year ago in webstorm, it should have been fixed I believe. The code should compile anyway

Comment: What IDE are you using? Please add it as a tag.

Comment: And it's Angular and not AngularJS, right? If so, change the tag.

Comment: Well, it may be my IDE but I can't tell if there is an error in the code or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `<any>` in front of the error to make the error report go away. I am not sure what type it is expected or why it is happening but this fix works for Typescript.

```
@Injectable(<any>{
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

or

```
@Injectable(({
    providedIn: 'root'
}) as any)
```